# Sudo sh script with curl and command line argument

Tags: linux, bash, sh, sudo

I'm trying run a sudoed curled bash script that takes in a command line argument but I'm having problem with the syntax. Using this, argument ($0) does not seem to get picked up with the script.

```
sudo sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/script/path/install.sh) argument"
```

Comment: Maybe `sudo bash -s argument < <(curl -sSL https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/script/path/install.sh)`

Comment: that hit the nail on the head. ty!

Comment: The value for `$0` should be a separate argument, i.e. `sudo sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/script/path/install.sh)" "argument"`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `-c` part on the beautiful [sh(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh):

> ***-c** string*
>
> If the **-c** option is present, then commands are read from string. **If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters**, starting with $0.

So all you'll need to do is to move the argument **after** the 'script'

```sh
sudo sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/script/path/install.sh)" 'argument'
```

Little test example:

```
sh -c 'echo "args: $0"' 'Test argument'
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzhDQTdZQT01OSNfQSmxKL3YSkHFQEldQT0ktbhEAShQmpuaV6L@/z8A)</sup>